# SEO-friendly links inside dropdown-menu

Tags: seo

What are the options for a dropdown menu?

- **`select`** - can't contain links
- div with ***initial*** display none - Might incur a penalty + might not be indexed
- div with ***onload*** display none by JavaScript - Might cause a flicker on load

Is there a better option?

Comment: Whats wrong with using `<ul>`?

Comment: @bybe Nothing. I didn't mean `div` as opposed to `ul`. I was just using that as a generic html tag.

Comment: Search engines do not penalize for `display:none` and display:none does not make content uncrawlable.

Comment: @bybe a) Thanks. b) You can transform your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS Hidden

Google and other search engines do not penalize sites for using `display:none` and in fact its extremely common that most sites use it for one reason or more.

JavaScript Content

Google and other search engines can understand JavaScript to some extent and again it is extremely common for websites to inject and modify things in the DOM.

Cloaking

What Google and other search engines look for is cloaking, intentional populating the web page without allow site visitors to view that content in anyway. Google can associate hidden content with triggers in both CSS, HTML and JavaScript.

There are dozens of ways that this can be done, from display none with no triggers to even going as far to use a small font and text color the same as the background color, therefor making the text invisible to site visitors but viewable by Google, but Google has been around for decades, it understands cloaking.